# Why you cannot close the process of anti virus software from task manager in windows?

Tags: windows, api

Is it because anti viurses runs in 'kernel mode' or do they have a special ACL?

I dind'nt find any thing on Google....

Comment: This is a programming forum. Try http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

If you would have been able to terminate AV process, then virus process also would have been doing that, thus bypassing AV security.

Comment: Most anti-virus software will tell Windows not to let it get terminated, so that viruses cannot easily kill the anti-virus.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the AV program has multiple executables running.

You can easily have each executable monitor each other to see if it's been terminated (not by the AV program, of course) and then relaunch the executable that has been terminated.